# How can I use argparse to parse a mutual exclusive argument group with defaults, so that only one of the arguments get a default value?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, argparse

I have the below mutual exclusive argument group (`group`), where I want the default to be `args.thread=10` and `args.process=None`, if neither `--thread` or `--process` is specified. Furhermore, if `--thread` or `--process` is specified, the other should be set to `None`.

With my current code, the result is always `args={ ..., 'thread': 10, 'process': 10, ... }`.

How can I fix my code to get the anticipated behavior?

```
fmt = lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, width=140)
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Atlassian Watchdog: Search through all resources on Confluence, Bitbucket, or Jira looking for secrets.', formatter_class=fmt)

group = p.add_argument_group('Concurrency')
group = group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-t', '--thread', type=int, default=10, metavar='N', dest='thread', help='number of threads (default: %(default)s)')
group.add_argument('-p', '--process', type=int, default=10, metavar='N', dest='process', help='number of subprocesses (default: %(default)s)')
```

Comment: Talk about confusing defaults!  Without trying to understand exactly what you want, I suggest sticking with the default `default`, `None`.  Then after parsing test `args.thread is None`, etc, and assign values as needed.  Don't try to do fancy stuff with defaults in parser itself.

Comment: I second what @hpaulj said. You could make the mutually exclusive group required and set the `action` for both to `store_true`. This means one option will always be `True` and the other `False`. Then assign the values yourself.

Comment: In `argparse` it is awkward to make the value of argument depend on the value of another, defaults or not.  Each is processed in the order it occurs, and normally without reference to other values.  Interactions are best handled after parsing, with you know the all the relevant values.  (Interactions within parsing require custom `Action` classes, and good knowledge of the argparse code itself.)